# Is it a good idea to load the css files from page.tpl file instead of .info file

Tags: theming, .info

I am just curious, because i am trying to get my site working for both IE and chrome, and I want it to load only a specific css file. Conditional stylesheets arent working for me, as I cannot see the change in the browser when I check it's html file.

Comment: Why Conditional stylesheets arent working for YOU only ?

Comment: @NikhilM I'm gonna take a stab that the OP is using IE10 - Microsoft dropped support for them

Comment: Anyway, question about .info vs .tpl.php for css is a good question. All points in my answer below are from experience, fixing stuff after guys who didn't bothered to ask it. We can disagree with the idea, but I really appreciate asking!

Answer (score 2):

It is bad idea, on so many levels I'm sure I can't list all.

- Conditionally included stylesheets will get cached by various proxies and served with no respect for original conditions.
- Modules like CDN will not be able to work on your CSS files to speed things up.
- Aggregation and cache modules will stop working as well.
- Search engine bots will get confused and may think you are trying to trick them by serving different version of a page to bot, and other one to bot disguised for an user - risk of google ban.
- If, in future, someone will redefine page.tpl.php for certain content types, you will have the same file described in many places - easy way for inconsistency and styling bugs.
- CSS provided by modules might end up in other position to your own than they are now, this can cause hard to diagnose display bugs.

Comment: ok thanks :).Then I guess I should try conditional stylesheets again, could you help me understand how using this statement       conditional-stylesheets[if lt IE 7][all][] = ie6-and-below.css  how can I have a condition for if it was in chrome. It seems like the stylesheets I specified for other browsers will still show up.

Comment: @user1675999 CSS questions are off topic here, please see [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) for help with IE conditional comments